# Centering a child div inside a parent div having a triangular shape generated using CSS3

Tags: html, css

How to position a child div inside a parent div. Here parent div is given a triangular shape using css3 border. I have given position relative to parent div and position absolute to child div ,but failed to center the child div. Even if we can position child div by giving static values ,I want a solution to calculate the dimensions dynamically.Please find the jsfiddle link below describing my issue.[jsfiddle.net/cnLbxs7f/](http://jsfiddle.net/cnLbxs7f/)

```
 <div id='frame' class="frame">

        <div class="triangle">**<!-- Parent div -->**
            <div class="triangle-child"></div>**<!-- Child div -->**
        </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Are the dimensions static or dynamic?

Comment: Dimensions need to be dynamic. I want to know how can we calculate the dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using static values to try center an element try using:

`margin:0 auto`

See this guide on CSS-Tricks for more information about [centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

**EDIT:**

Please see revised [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnLbxs7f/4/).

This makes use of the calc function on the `.triangle-child` class in under to keep it centered.

```
.triangle-child {
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     background-color: coral;
     left: calc(100% - 12px);
     position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Requirement is to center the child div inside the parent div. Here child div is the one with class="triangle-child" and parent div  with class="triangle"

Comment: Manoj , thanks for your effort. The revised fiddle doesn't center the child div(both vertically and horizontally). Also the 12px that you have used in calc, is that static.